# Is it okay for me to comment to try to influence the approval of a suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-question

I voted to close a bad question, and then I noticed there was a pending edit which, while slightly improving the grammar, made the question even worse by adding another off-topic component. It's two hours until I can vote on suggested edits, but I noticed a couple of people had already approved it, so I added this comment:

> Please do not approve the suggested edit. The question is inherently too broad and opinion-based, and the edit does nothing to correct this while adding a request for a software recommendation.

I immediately doubted whether or not I should have done this. Is it inappropriate to try to influence voting like this?

Comment: *"Is it inappropriate"* I'd say yes, considering you can't see comments in the suggested edit review. Leaving a comment does little to influence the edit's approval.

Comment: I do sometimes leave the "don't polish turds" as a rejection reason, but as a comment on the post itself it's just distracting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intentions were good.

However, the comment was not really needed. I do not believe that edit reviewers even see the comment, and people viewing the post were more than likely not the majority of who was reviewing the pending edit.

Furthermore, it is generally discouraged to discuss meta topics in comments on a question which is essentially what the latter portion of your comment does.

As this was more than likely a statistical outlier in your general use of the site, I am not sure there is much more to say about this situation in broader terms.

Going forward, I would suggest spending less time on these types of posts, and more time either finding high quality posts or more time working on answering high quality posts.